# Помощь с циклом

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Сама задача заключается в том, чтобы найти количество делителей числа n.
Проблема в том, что не могу в массиве (векторе) правильно составить "условие". Расскажу на примере.
Допустим у нас есть массив с элементами 2 2 3. 0 элемент массива равен 0 + 1, значит счетчик увеличиваем на 1, если элемент не равен следующему элементу, нужно выполнить другое действие. Проблема, что при сравнении выхожу за рамки массива, затем крэш программы. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n, p = 2, c = 1;
vector <int> the_vector;

cin >> n;

while(n > 1){
    if(n % p == 0){
        n /= p;
        the_vector.push_back(p);
    }
    else p++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < (int)the_vector.size(); i++){
    if(the_vector[i] == the_vector[i + 1]) c++;
    else c *= (c + 1);
}

cout << c;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это выражение: `the_vector[i + 1]` -- очевидно вылетит на последнем индексе. Поскольку вы сравниваете текущий индекс со следующим, почему бы не пробегать цикл до *предпоследнего* индекса?

---

Вот примерная реализация того, о чём говорилось в комментариях:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    // первый шаг: найти делители (у вас он есть)    
    vector <int> divisors;
    int p = 2;

    while (n > 1)
    {
        if (n % p == 0)
        {
            n /= p;
            divisors.push_back(p);
        }
        else
        {
            p++;
        }
    }

    // второй шаг: подсчитать количество, сколько раз встречается каждый делитель
    vector<int> divisorQuantities;
    int lastProcessedDivisor = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)divisors.size(); i++)
    {
        int currentDivisor = divisors[i];
        if (currentDivisor == lastProcessedDivisor)
            divisorQuantities[divisorQuantities.size() - 1]++; // last
        else
            divisorQuantities.push_back(1);
        lastProcessedDivisor = currentDivisor;
    }

    // третий шаг: перемножить, увеличив на 1
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)divisorQuantities.size(); i++)
        c *= divisorQuantities[i] + 1;

    cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В примере 2 2 3 - 3 не попадает в область "проверки". В алгоритме нам нужно посчитать сколько раз будет повторяться число...: (n1 + 1)(n2 + 1)...(nK + 1) в алгоритме n - кол-во повторений числа. С примером 2 2 3 - (2 + 1)*(1+1) = 6. 2 2 3 - каноническое разложение числа 12, с помощью него мы находим кол-во делителей числа.

Comment: Лучше взять контрпример к числу 2. (2 + 1) = 2 - 2 делителя числа 2.

Comment: @Владислав Бабенко: тогда ваш цикл вообще неверен. `c++` верно только на первом сомножителе. Зачем так сложно? Делайте по-другому, за два прохода. На первом проходе посчитайте все n1, n2, ... и запомните их в новый vector, потом пройдите по этому вектору и перемножьте.

Comment: А если у нас много множителей? 2, 3, 5, 7, ... - простые числа.

Comment: @Владислав Бабенко: а именно вы видите проблему? Да, может быть много. Максимум log_2 (maxint) = log_2 (2^64) = 64.

Comment: Скорость работы.

Comment: @Владислав Бабенко: Вектор длиной в аж 64 элемента замедлит работу на десяток наносекунд. Мне кажется, вы гораздо большего прироста производительности добьётесь (в тысячи раз), если перейдёте на более быстрые алгоритмы нахождения целых делителей.

Comment: @Владислав Бабенко: ну вот, набросал метод.

Answer (score 1):

Если решать конкретно проблему выхода за пределы вектора, то лучше воспользоваться итераторами:

```
for (auto it = the_vector.begin(); it != the_vector.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it + 1 == the_vector.end())
        break;

    if (*it == *(it + 1))
        c++;
    else
        c *= (c + 1);
}
```

Это безотносительно того, как там должен работать алгоритм решения задачи, только для проверки выхода за пределы. Если я ошибся - поправьте, пожалуйста.

**UPD:** убрал ++it, --it...

Comment: @VladD Может я чего-то не понимаю, тогда попрошу помощь в понятия алгоритма и его реализации. http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=solution&id_task=171 По сути, половина сделана, а именно нахождение множителей, а как затем довести их до ума, я немного не понял ваш вариант.

Comment: А почему вместо простого (it + 1) вы увеличиваете и потом снова уменьшаете итератор?

Comment: @VladD, да, что-то я про это забыл)

Comment: @Владислав Бабенко: Ну смотрите. Первый шаг вы сделали -- нашли множители. Второй шаг -- посчитать числа n1, n2, ... Третий шаг -- найти их произведение, предварительно увеличив на 1. Вы пытаетесь соединить второй и третий шаг, и вам не удаётся. Сделайте сначала проще, сначала второй. потом третий.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проще без всяких векторов и т.д.

```
long long n;
int ans = 0;
scanf("%d", &n);

for(long long k = n, l = 2; k > 1; )
{
        if(k % l)
        {
             if(l * l > k)
                  l = k;
             else
                 l++;
        }
        else
        {
            k /= l;
            ans++;
            //printf("%d ",l); // простой делитель
        }
}
ans *= 2;
printf("\n%d\n", ans); // ответ
```

Будем искать положительные делители для обычного натурального числа, в конце просто умножим на 2

1) Берем за первый делитель 2 делим на 2 пока не будет делиться с остатком

2) Увеличиваем на 1 пока  не будет опять делиться без остатка
и т.д.

1. Вопрос может возникнуть в том что он может посчитать 4ку или 6 ку как делитель но не будет потому что когда ты по максимум делишь на 2 дальше на 4 делиться не будет уже
2. Есть теорема то что составное число имеет делитель не больший квадратного корня из этого числа, этот пункт нам гораздо помогает увеличить производительность

Comment: ой, только мое решение просто выводит кол-во всех простых делителей, ну можно внести пару измененеий и все, и опять же без векторов можно

Comment: @risonyo: Вы и вправду сумеете выполнить задание без хранения промежуточных результатов? Это не так просто, кстати. Если да, напишите решение.

Comment: @risonyo программа будет работать большое кол-во времени. Если вас так заинтересовало - http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=171 1 <= N <= 10^18. Думаете ваша программа уложиться в одну секунду?

Comment: @risonyo считает не правильно. Контрпример: ввод 12, вывод 6.

Comment: Я так и не понимаю, как можно реализовать метод @VladD лол. Это вечер?)

Comment: Теперь проверь еще раз

Comment: Вот теперь работает

Comment: правда для 10^18 не работает

Comment: выводит 0

объясни метод, если понимаешь, пожалуйста.